# GroupBy with property in a nested child collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

I have a query which consists of a collection of Activities. 
-Each Activity can be done in more than one country therefore the Activity has a child collection of ActivityCountries. 
-Each ActivityCountry is associated with the Country table in order for me to get the Country Name. 
-Each Activity has a field called BudgetTotal.

I need a collection that groups on the CountryCode in the ActivityCountries child collection and returns me the Sum(BudgetTotal) and the CountryName by grouped country.
I start off with my list of Activities (this list can change due to filters on the page which is why I want to re-use this collection).

```
var activities = GetFilteredActivities();
```

I then try to simplify it by getting the list of all Activities and ActivityCountries

```
var countries = activities.SelectMany(a => a.ActivityCountries);
```

Then I try to group them by CountryCode and return the CountryName and Sum(BudgetTotal). This is where I'm having a problem.
I've tried:

```
var b = countries.GroupBy(g => g.CountryCode)
                                .Select new
                                {
                                    CountryName = <something>.Country.CountryName,
                                    Total = Sum(<something>.BudgetTotal)
                                }
```

I realize that this doesn't work but I'm trying to figure out how to get the Country Name and the Sum(BudgetTotal) from here. I also have to OrderByDescending on the Sum(BudgetTotal). I've seen many examples but none of them that suits what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're close...

```
var b = countries
    .GroupBy(c => c.CountryCode)
    .Select(g => new
        {
            CountryName = g.First().Country.CountryName,  // assuming that there is 1 country code per country name
            Total = g.Sum(x => x.BudgetTotal)
        })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Total);
```